# How to plot/stream data from a csv file in python?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a csv file with the following columns {time,x,y,z} and approximately 100000 rows. I would like to "live stream/animate" the data in real time so that I can get an overview of what is happening.

attempt:

```
def generate_pieces(file, piecesize=128):

piece = []
for i, line in enumerate(file): 
    if (i % piecesize == 0 and i > 0):
        yield piece
        del piece[:]
    piece.append(line)
yield piece

file = csv.reader(open('file_name.csv'))
for piece in generate_pieces(file):
        x_data = []
        y_data = []
        z_data = []            
        t_vec = []

        for row in piece:
            x_data.append(row[1])
            y_data.append(row[2])
            z_data.append(row[3])
            d = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S')
            d_simp = (d.hour+ (1/60)*d.minute + (1/3600)*d.second)
            conversion = 86400*d.day+3600*d.hour+60*d.minute + d.second                               
            t_vec.append(conversion)                            

        x_data = [int(i) for i in x_data] # Converts values to int type.    
        y_data = [int(i) for i in y_data]        
        z_data = [int(i) for i in z_data]
```

So my attempt involves taking pieces of data of length 128. From here I want to stream 128 points at a time in a live plot? I am not sure where to go from here

Comment: There is no animation in the code. Did you seach for "matplotlib animation"? In how far do the results not help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using matplotlib for this purpose, it can help plot data in intervals with animation

sample code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import matplotlib.animation as animation

figure = plot.figure()
axis= figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animateplots(i):

    #Prepare data for plot 
    axis.clear()
    axis.plot(x,y,z)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(figure, animateplots, interval=<intended interval>)
plot.show()
```

Hope my understanding of your problem is correct, if so consider reading about more about matplotlib for graph plotting needs

Comment: Thanks for the useful feedback. So I should pass each of my pieces to the animateplots function inside my for loop? thanks

Comment: Configure the interval  alone .. pass all the data at once..  also you can test the plot animation by using a staggered approch of passing data. See the behaviour